# Python selenium webdriver opens blank page

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I can´t find a solution for this, when i try to open this page https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/ works fine, but when i try to add 'list-1/' it just goes white and i don´t know what to do.

https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/list-1/

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def NavigateUrl(strURL):
   myWebdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path+'/chromedriver.exe')
   myWebdriver.get(strURL) 
   time.sleep(2)
   return myWebdriver


start_urls = ['https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/']

if __name__ == "__main__":

for url in start_urls:
    url = url + 'list-1/'
    page_navigation = NavigateUrl(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    page_navigation.quit()
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried adding a few seconds to your sleep time? maybe it doesn't load a blank page, but it takes longer than a few seconds to load it, and you close it too soon.

Comment: @Beek I will try, wait me a second

Comment: It doesn´t work

Comment: I realize that the page gives me a 429 response

Comment: using Requests package: answer is here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939793/python-requests-429-response-any-way-to-bypass/66955512#66955512)