# python requests 429 response. Any way to bypass?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, data-mining, data-extraction

I am trying to scrape data from this website:

```
https://www.realestate.com.au/find-agent/victoria-park-wa-6100?page=1&source=results
```

but when I send a requests to this link it return 429 response. Please anyone can help me to solve this issue

My Code:

```
import requests


headers = {
    'authority':'www.realestate.com.au',
    'method':'GET',
    'path':'/find-agent/victoria-park-wa-6100?page=2&source=results',
    'scheme':'https',
    'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control':'max-age=0',
    'cookie':'reauid=97fa56b87e4a0000f2385760e50300009f5d0f00; mid=14438305973304081772; s_vi=[CS]v1|302B9C7D549B351B-400019144A08CC6D[CE]; s_ecid=MCMID%7C41762198941431542153915924747747631103; VT_LANG=language%3Den-US; _fbp=fb.2.1616328959328.1411085120; mako_fpc_id=f3b48060-6ca0-468b-8417-5c4331844f22; s_nr=1616329068252; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1616329142109r0.5813387456564119; QSI_SI_41tFIUPeSKv873L_intercept=true; Country=PK; KP_UID=d67a8604-7a55-ac63-2939-33605bab499e; AWSELB=BD21ABD912FD962534A86FF37C471AF8CEA612D2DA2EA79D0C4C2C0C12582F925E886BFF2B41577284C9C9332FB9815B2C31177FDADF0414684498FC6684185E03DAFE8405; AWSELBCORS=BD21ABD912FD962534A86FF37C471AF8CEA612D2DA2EA79D0C4C2C0C12582F925E886BFF2B41577284C9C9332FB9815B2C31177FDADF0414684498FC6684185E03DAFE8405; AMCVS_341225BE55BBF7E17F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; _stc=typedBookmarked; s_cc=true; _gid=GA1.3.18226979.1617461578; id5id.1st_last=1617461596633; id5id.1st=%20%7B%20%22created_at%22%3A%20%222021-03-21T12%3A16%3A10Z%22%2C%20%22id5_consent%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22original_uid%22%3A%20%22ID5-ZHMOgkOOAbPohthleKT8pkJQyU4qgaQLzVhn2vjkdQ!%22%2C%20%22universal_uid%22%3A%20%22ID5-ZHMOlX7LDRWCg5thfmHmJYTpjMpYoxNkps0RO4mHMg!%22%2C%20%22signature%22%3A%20%22ID5_AVH0GTjpdbBHqWV59BP1-i8JEjSp8aybqVzONYmXhddYziHVh_rLdvcsTPnzZz3HIs2ri9B26KW9Z91dH2DMfnU%22%2C%20%22link_type%22%3A%202%2C%20%22cascade_needed%22%3A%20true%7D; id5id.1st_123_nb=0; AMCV_341225BE55BBF7E17F000101%40AdobeOrg=-330454231%7CMCIDTS%7C18721%7CMCMID%7C41762198941431542153915924747747631103%7CMCAAMLH-1618132227%7C3%7CMCAAMB-1618132227%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1617534627s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7C302B9C7D549B351B-400019144A08CC6D%7CvVersion%7C3.1.2; _sp_ses.2fe7=*; _ga=GA1.3.1408343425.1616328955; QSI_HistorySession=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.realestate.com.au%2Ffind-agent%2Fvictoria-park-wa-6100%3Fpage%3D1%26source%3Dresults~1617527430603; KP_UIDz=F4XHgsQV9c%2FTQzll5Ndulg%3D%3D%3A%3A5IsfhjHoNmnkht19ND97crnQoMskUJ6aIoCOa8EPwoXMwlMMS47PUmEZSHeeyPI83MXIH%2F9C%2BxMMGCWyl0ApKdv616egyT7xhhLGmw2jal4LA1Ml3dHb8uhosY7j1eXPCWC1bL%2FCWgdwrt5tPoarmvSfzz7SLbZep6ETdU83TKp%2BVqcFobRaam91qFzw02WRwiEQtgeBKGo2cnE9PzRdGTtYhWFAT6TZeKjmeSQOTsOftptuJO%2B833w7vUsSQkIM5zxsk1Qb8sZJnhBokdV8sbdyRu39hKFppEbDHLY%2BnItOkrNGBraYsgNgg%2BLFGEchLvHFtfCfCXzugFW9f5piym0247JXapdyez5mwoVbuW444Eefc5i7MOAsXxEjVa%2BBtK0%2BqVAma5QbOF6McCBMgMzZvvKkd4LNCNYGOXoNc9zvACln1vSbJy7XlKQMmGcajYV1tRuifffi%2BGwRWWeQ%2FTd6eWVarXc48n7seoWl80mYX6LK7HCXoXq0BH5X%2BiTjT%2BSKwK7w%2FqMXQcgt%2FfErDnZhEr2auXw%2FnGA0reE8SyU%3D; pageview_counter.srs=6; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; _sp_id.2fe7=c11fc61a-511f-444b-b13d-e6f2c8fb6b8a.1616328956.10.1617527442.1617468348.ab95c4fd-1806-47b2-a4b5-aad4a1e4103f; _ga_F962Q8PWJ0=GS1.1.1617527427.11.1.1617527441.0; utag_main=v_id:017854b683fe0022250ca432779003072002806a00ac2$_sn:10$_ss:0$_st:1617529241850$vapi_domain:realestate.com.au$dc_visit:10$ses_id:1617527426094%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$dc_event:2%3Bexp-session$dc_region:ap-southeast-2%3Bexp-session; External=%2FAPPNEXUS%3D4266307067876008443%2FCASALE%3DX5bknF4BHoabg%252EzfklIojAAA%2526910%2FPUBMATIC%3DE3F1E12A-9392-415E-BFA3-8E9A2D3A6383%2FRUBICON%3DKGQO4LPG-4-7Y1I%2FTRIPLELIFT%3D160265391696123554%2F_EXP%3D1649063429%2F_exp%3D1649063441',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/find-agent/victoria-park-wa-6100?page=1&source=results'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


print(r.status_code)
```

Output:

```
429
```

Comment: You sent more requests than the site allows. Wait some time to be unblocked. You can use the time to implement a limiter.

Comment: @KlausD. this is the first time I send requests to this website.

Comment: The keywords is request**s** here. How many in what timeframe?

Comment: @MalikIbrahim it seems it's normal that it returns 429, the result loads some cookies the first time and loads some JS script (that set some more cookies) then loads the same initial url with the correct cookies

Comment: @BertrandMartel will you please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: @MalikIbrahim I would print the result of the 429 response request, look at which JS script url are loaded, use requests.Session() to persist the cookies and load them one after another

Comment: @BertrandMartel I try but I think it is not correctly done by me will you please send me the code in which you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the search on a standard browser, you see a page 429 also in the network tab (F12 developer tools). I don't know how you built your headers and where you get it from, but the cookies are of primary importance here. Especially the items "KP_UIDz" and "KP_UID".

The following code works for me :

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/find-agent/victoria-park-wa-6100?page=1&source=results'
s = rq.Session()

headers = {
"Host": "www.realestate.com.au",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Referer": "https://www.realestate.com.au/find-agent/victoria-park-wa-6100",
"Cookie":  "KP_UIDz=fxINWtvcCUSmOElOEVDUtA%3D%3D%3A%3ATttOpt%2FDO7HlYzZedmreLNB%2FZ39%2FHjUPNaT%2FA%2BLweO7JKXJP7SYoAD6VTztnQDRGWRpaoBGCLLYczrKHZ00KZo%2BthnlfT7c5f3SAFCsxwf3%2FeOY15LXdfeymzsR7BKd%2Buwh21Hf5p8XlSs%2BsmXYy47G4Kw3S9ennT2q3nXXz8gXWlqX8neOhg1hDuV%2BB%2BH5WZoXPPwqcnR3HLfv5IHhN4Ou%2BaS6n1hkjhGv8mN6ku4JlAyY%2BoVqYVESwZxgbxF09zegcWVBAC1vtZv8sdDzkVfkeYW4j7zcVsK6UeDrBB8fOH0eIngTtulnYT25cI9r%2FpgBBtWrygLrprmAxpDBskwaRduJcTt0Cud7xp8YuPpTA1wbxCq5UyAaI1HoKPJtuvikA28pmDV79Udv6lwD6z48WfyfnUl9RIO1f1xeHkcKvOLDcd74GUEg3A6x8HuIVqaIfQd%2FcQhOJoWEQG2vTbSe04r9gRHZgWnV4IZOPPatAkAqvMnGBrSZsWfoV4AXT;  KP_UID=b89f9896-2bd6-148c-7f02-c5abee0cc14e",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"TE": "Trailers"
}

q = s.get(url, headers=headers)
print(q.status_code) # give 200
soup = bs(q.content, "lxml")
```

As a proof the parsing part returns the data for each agent:

```
rr = soup.find_all("div", class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("agent-card__details"))

full_data = []
for j in range(len(rr)):

    labels = rr[j].find_all("div", class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("key-feature__label"))
    vals = rr[j].find_all("div", class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("key-feature__value"))
    name = rr[j].find_all("div", class_="agent-profile__name")

    labels = [i.text for i in labels]
    vals = [i.text for i in vals]
    name = name[0].text
    # print(name)

    data = list(zip(labels, vals))
    data.insert(0, name)
    full_data.append(data)
```

"full_data" contains :

```
[['Edward Lim',
  ('Properties sold(as lead agent)', '24'),
  ('Median sold price', '$420k'),
  ('Median days advertised', '68'),
  ('PropertiessoldProperties sold', '46')],
 ['Lee & Derek Baston',
  ('Properties sold(as lead agent)', '21'),
  ('Median sold price', '$655k'),
  ('Median days advertised', '41'),
  ('PropertiessoldProperties sold', '48')],
 ['Fulton Borthwick',
  ('Properties sold(as lead agent)', '7'),
  ('Median sold price', '$515k'),
  ('Median days advertised', '71'),
  ('PropertiessoldProperties sold', '18')],
....
....
```